# Isomorphism of R modules $R^{n} \cong M \oplus N$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a  PID. Show that if $R^{n} \cong M \oplus N$ for R- modules M and N then $M \cong R^{k}$ and $N \cong R^{n-k}$ for some k.

I tried to rewrite M and N as $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{k} R / a_{i} R$ and $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{m} R / b_{i} R$ but I stuck a bit.

Comment: It is well known that a submodule of a free module is free when the ring is a PID.

Comment: I would add : if you followed the proof of the structure theorem, which you seem to be using here, then you know this fact